# How to use @rid in OrientDB?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I'm new to OrientDB. I would like to use the functionalities of OrientDB, however, my mind is a little bit confused with the usage of @rid function.

I have read the web documentation of the application and group discussions, and I am trying to figure out the concepts.

I apologise for any cross-posting about the issue. I couldn’t understand the usage of (@rid). In an online application, how do we understand and use the @rid value of a vertex or node?

Do we have to use all of them? How can we traverse without using @rid? How can we be sure about the 11:4 value in a framework that produces such kind of dynamic query?

```
select from 11:4 where any() traverse(0,10) (address.city = 'Rome')
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the Record ID (rid for short) of a OrientDB database. It uniquely identifies a record within the **database**. Some databases use a globally unique identifier (MongoDB) or a primary key (RDBMS). These are all similar concepts.

Because OrientDB is "several databases in one", record translates to

- Document, if using the document database (API)
- Vertex or Edge, if using the Graph database (API)
- Object, if using the Object Database (API)

So in your example `11:4` means the fifth record (first record is 0) in cluster 11 (first cluster is also 0). This is a (almost) **direct pointer** to the **physical** record in the database. That becomes the starting point of your traversal. Key to understand is that you have *very fast access to your data without using an index lookup*.